# Write a C program to create a copy of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to write a copy_list function that creates a linked list(the function result) with new nodes that contain the same data as the linked list referenced by the single argument of copy_list.But my copy_list function doesn't work.It goes into infinite loop,While loop doesn't quit. 
My structures

```
typedef struct name_node_s {
  char name[11];
  struct name_node_s *restp;
}name_node_t;
typedef struct {
  name_node_t *headp;
  int size;
}name_list_t;
```

My copy_list function:

```
name_node_t *copy_list(name_node_t *head){
    name_node_t *current = head;
    name_node_t *newList = NULL;
    name_node_t *tail = NULL;

    while (current != NULL){
        if (newList == NULL) {
            newList = malloc(sizeof(name_node_t));
            strcpy(newList->name, current->name);
            newList->restp = NULL;
            tail = newList;
        }
        else {
            tail->restp = malloc(sizeof(name_node_t));
            tail = tail->restp;
            strcpy(tail->name, current->name);
            tail->restp = NULL;
        }
        current = current->restp;
    }
    return(newList);
}
```

Rest of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct name_node_s {
  char name[11];
  struct name_node_s *restp;
}name_node_t;
typedef struct {
  name_node_t *headp;
  int size;
}name_list_t;
name_node_t* presidents(void);
void insertAfter(name_node_t* mynode,name_node_t* newNode);
//void delete_last(name_node_t** headRef);
//void ListDelete(name_list_t* listP, char pname[]);
void lastDelete(name_list_t* listP);
void place_first(name_node_t **headRef, char pname[]);
name_node_t *copy_list(name_node_t *head);
int main(void)
{
  name_list_t list;
  name_list_t list_two;
  //name_node_t *np, *qp;
  list.headp = presidents();
  name_node_t *new_node;
  new_node = malloc(sizeof(name_node_t));
  strcpy(new_node->name, "Eisenhower");
  insertAfter(list.headp->restp, new_node);
  lastDelete(&list);
  place_first(&list.headp, "Mustafa");
  printf("%s %s %s %s", list.headp->name, list.headp->restp->name, list.headp->restp->restp->name, list.headp->restp->restp->restp->name);
  list_two.headp = copy_list(list.headp);
  printf("%s %s %s %s", list_two.headp->name, list.headp->restp->name, list.headp->restp->restp->name, list.headp->restp->restp->restp->name);

  return(0);
}
name_node_t* presidents(void)
{
  name_node_t* head = NULL;
  name_node_t* second = NULL;
  name_node_t* third = NULL;

  head = malloc(sizeof(name_node_t));
  second = malloc(sizeof(name_node_t));
  third = malloc (sizeof(name_node_t));

  strcpy(head->name, "Washington");
  head->restp = second;

  strcpy(second->name, "Roosevelt");
  second->restp = third;

  strcpy(third->name, "Kennedy");
  third->restp = NULL;

  return(head);
}
void insertAfter(name_node_t* mynode,name_node_t* newNode)
{
    newNode->restp = mynode->restp;
    mynode->restp = newNode;
}

void ListDelete(name_list_t* listP, char pname[]){
    name_node_t *to_freep, *cur_nodep;
    if(strcmp(listP->headp->name, pname)){
        to_freep = listP->headp;
        listP->headp = to_freep->restp;
        --(listP->size);
    }
    else {
        for (cur_nodep = listP->headp;
            cur_nodep->restp != NULL && !strcmp(cur_nodep->restp->name, pname);
            cur_nodep = cur_nodep->restp) {
                if( cur_nodep->restp != NULL && strcmp(cur_nodep->restp->name, pname)) {
                    to_freep = cur_nodep->restp;
                    cur_nodep->restp = to_freep->restp;
                    free(to_freep);
                    --(listP->size);
                }
            }
        }
    }
void lastDelete(name_list_t* listP){
    name_node_t *to_freep, *cur_nodep;
    for (cur_nodep = listP->headp;
            cur_nodep->restp != NULL;
            cur_nodep = cur_nodep->restp) {}
    to_freep = cur_nodep;
    cur_nodep->restp = to_freep->restp;
    free(to_freep);
    --(listP->size);
}
void place_first(name_node_t **headRef, char pname[]) {
    name_node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(name_node_t));
    strcpy(newNode->name, pname);
    newNode->restp = *headRef;
    *headRef = newNode;
}
/*name_node_t *copy_list(name_node_t *head) {
    name_node_t *current = head;
    name_node_t *newList = NULL;
    name_node_t **lastPtr;

    lastPtr = &newList;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("**");
        place_first(lastPtr, current->name);
        lastPtr = &((*lastPtr)->restp);
        current = current->restp;
    }
    return(newList);
}*/
/*name_node_t *copy_list(name_node_t *head) {
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else {
        name_node_t *newList = malloc(sizeof(name_list_t));
        strcpy(newList->name, head->name);
        newList->restp = copy_list(head->restp);

        return(newList);
    }
}*/
/name_node_t *copy_list(name_node_t *head){
    name_node_t *current = head;
    name_node_t *newList = NULL;
    name_node_t *tail = NULL;

    while (current != NULL){
        if (newList == NULL) {
            newList = malloc(sizeof(name_node_t));
            strcpy(newList->name, current->name);
            newList->restp = NULL;
            tail = newList;
        }
        else {
            tail->restp = malloc(sizeof(name_node_t));
            tail = tail->restp;
            strcpy(tail->name, current->name);
            tail->restp = NULL;
        }
        current = current->restp;
    }
    return(newList);
}
```

Comment: You should always check if `malloc` returns `NULL`. If you don't you've introduced yourself a bug and (likely) a security hole. *Why the hell don't give compilers warnings about this?!*

Comment: It goes into infinite loop,While loop doesn't quit.

Comment: Add a `printf("%s\n", current->name);` right after `while`. Then you can at least see what your loop is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `lastDelete()`, this loop:

```
for (cur_nodep = listP->headp;
            cur_nodep->restp != NULL;
            cur_nodep = cur_nodep->restp) {}
```

... stops at the last node in the list. Afterwards you never set `restp` to `NULL` in the *second-to-last* element. You only work on the last one as `to_freep` and `cur_nodep` point to the same element.

Answer (score 0):

This may be easier to do recursively, since singly-linked lists are recursive structures:

- A copy of NULL is just NULL.
- A copy of a `name_node_t` is a freshly `malloc`'d `name_node_t` with the same `name` as the original and a *copy* of the original's `restp` as its `restp`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I wrote C++. Still:

Doesn't look like there's anything in copy_list that should make it go into an infinite loop.

The logic has:
`while (current!=null) current = current->next;`

Perhaps copy_list is being passed in a bad list? (i.e A list where the last element does not have `restp == null`).

In main you are calling:
insertAfter(....); 
lastDelete(....);
...
copy_list(....);

So the problem could be in insertAfter or lastDelete ... or ...

Check lastDelete:

```
 name_node_t *to_freep, *cur_nodep;
 for (cur_nodep = listP->headp;
        cur_nodep->restp != NULL;
        cur_nodep = cur_nodep->restp) {}
 to_freep = cur_nodep;
 cur_nodep->restp = to_freep->restp;
 free(to_freep);   //what if listP->headp was null? i.e. list had size 0?
--(listP->size);
```

Plenty of issues

1. What if you're passed a list with 0 elements?
2. What if you're passed a list with 1 element?
3. In any case after you free "to_freep", the node prior to "to_freep" does not have it's restp set to null. So the second last node, now points to a deleted node! This means the list never terminates.

A better lastDelete: (just an algo, can't remember the syntax anymore...)

```
if (head == null) return; //do nothing
if (head->next == null) 
{
  listP->head = null;
  listP->size = 0;
  return;
}
node* prev = head;
head = head->next;
while (head->next != null)
{
   prev = head;
   head = head->next;
}
//now prev points to a 2nd last node
//head points to last node
free(head);
prev->restp = null;
```

Comment: Neither the OP nor you are using C++ anywhere …